# What does の mean in this sentence?

Tags: particles

I cannot understand what の, right after で, is doing here. Could I rewrite this sentence without it?

> 日本で**の**留学のために、もっと日本語を勉強しなければならない。

Comment: If it were not for the bold の, 日本で would modify the next *verb*, 勉強する ("I must *study in Japan* for 留学...")

Comment: ^ Right, 日本で is adverbial, while 日本での is adjectival.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewite it as

good: 日本留学のために、もっと日本語を勉強しなければならない。

gpood: 日本に留学するために、もっと日本語を勉強しなければならない。

accseptable: 日本で留学するために、もっと日本語を勉強しなければならない。

unnatural: 日本で留学のために、もっと日本語を勉強しなければならない。

The word "で" requires "場所(place)" before it and "動作(action)" after it.

Thus, "日本(place) で留学する(action)."

So "で" is usually used the following situation.

> "私が結婚するって、どこで知ったの？" Where did you know that I'm going to get married?
> "学校で聞いた。" I heard it at the school.
>
> "車が故障しちゃった。" My car had gone down.
> "どこで修理するの？" Where are you gong to repair it?
> "国道沿いの修理工場で修理します。" I'll repair it at the repair plant on the national route.

The verb phrase of an action after "で" is natural. On the other hand, the noun phrase of an action after "での" is natural.

> "（場所）で勉強する"
> "（場所）での勉強"

Precisely, "留学（する）" means that I go to somewhere and study something there.

Then not just "で" but "へ" is natural. "日本へ留学する" or "日本に留学する"

"日本で勉強する" is natural but "日本で留学する" is a little bit unnatural, because "留学" requires two contries, one is country of departure and the other is destination. "勉強" requires just the plase where you do something.

> So "留学" and "勉強" are properly used
> "インドネシアから日本へ（に）留学して、日本で勉強する。"

Comment: 渡航（移動）自体は主眼ではなく、現地に滞在して何かを学ぶために日本語を勉強するという文脈ですから、ここでの「日本での留学」や「日本で留学するために」という表現は、個人的には何も問題がない気がします。